# Add-to-cart coding is that correct with form?

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conn.php");

$action = $_POST['action'];
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

if(empty($user)){
echo"<script>alert('Please log in!');window.location='Log In.php';</script>";
exit;
}

if($action == 'add'){
$cart_arr = array(
  'foodID'=>$_POST['foodID'],
  'order_num'=>$_POST['order_num'],
  'food_type'=>$_POST['food_type'],
  );

  $cart_session = $_SESSION['cart_'.$user];
  if(empty($cart_session)){
      $cart_session[$cart_arr['foodID']] = $cart_arr;
  } else if(!empty($cart_session[$cart_arr['foodID']])){
      $cart_session[$cart_arr['foodID']]['order_num']+=$cart_arr['order_num'];
  } else {
      echo $cart_session[$cart_arr['foodID']] = $cart_arr;
  }

  $_SESSION['cart_'.$user] = $cart_session;
  } else if($action == 'clear'){
      $_SESSION['cart_'.$user]=array();
      echo"<script>alert('Shopping cart is empty, return home!');window.location='homepage.php';</script>";
      exit;

  } else if($action == 'change'){
      $temp_cart = $_SESSION['cart_'.$user];
      foreach($temp_cart as $k=>$v){
          if($_POST['goods_'.$k]!= $v['order_num']){
              $temp_cart[$k]['order_num'] = $_POST['goods_'.$k];
          }

    if($_POST['goods_'.$k] == 0){
        unset($temp_cart[$k]);
    }
   }

   $_SESSION['cart_'.$user] = $temp_cart;
   }

   if(empty($_SESSION['cart_'.$user])){
       echo"<script>alert('Shopping cart is empty, please add some orders!');window.location = 'homepage.php';</script>";

    exit;
 }

 $goods_id = array();
 $cart = $_SESSION['cart_'.$user];
 $v['food_type'] = $_POST['food_type'];
 foreach($cart as $k=>$v){
     $goods_id[$v['foodID']] = $v['foodID'];
 }

 $goods_id_str = implode(",",$goods_id);
 mysql_query("set names utf8");
 $sql = "select * from foodmenu where foodID IN (".$goods_id_str.")";
 $query = mysql_query($sql);
 $cart_goods = array();
 while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     $cart_goods[$arr['foodID']] = $arr;
 }

 foreach($cart as $k=>$v){
     $cart[$k]['food_name'] = $cart_goods[$k]['food_name'];
     $cart[$k]['food_img'] = str_replace("../","",$cart_goods[$k]['food_img']);
     $cart[$k]['food_price'] = $cart_goods[$k]['food_price'];
     $cart[$k]['food_description'] = $_POST['food_description'];
 }

?>
```

May I know is that this coding correct?
Because it shows blank page when it click on the button on previous php for add-to-cart purpose and it just shows normal header at the top.
I will attach form to access this php.

```
<div class="detailtop">
    <?php    

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foodmenu where foodID = '$foodID'"); 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             ?>
        <dl>
            <dt>
            <img src="<?php echo  $row["food_img"];?>" /> </dt>
            <dd>
    <form action="order.php" method="get" name="send" onSubmit="return Check()"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h3><?php echo  $row["food_name"];?></h3>
                <div class="detailtips">
                    <?php echo  $row["food_description"];?>
                </div>
                <p><span>Restaurant:</span><strong><?php echo  $row["restaurant_name"];?></strong></p>
                <p><span>Type :</span><strong><?php echo  $row["food_type"];?></strong></p>
                <p><span>Price :</span>RM &nbsp;<strong><?php echo  $row["food_price"];?><input name="num"  type="hidden" class="num" value="<?php echo  $row["food_price"];?>" /></strong></p>

                <div class="order" style=" padding-top:20px; padding-left:20px;">
                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo  $row["foodID"];?>" />
                <input name="" type="submit"  value="" class="ordersubmit" style=" margin-left:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                </div>
                </form>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you specify the problem more precisely? It is not clear how the two PHP files interact, and it is unknown what their name is. And what is a "normal header"?

Comment: Sorry for uploading the wrong coding just now.....Upper part is order.php as in the coding below......My problem is when click on the submit button it will come out with food img, food name, food type and the price, but it didn't come out when click the button. It just shows the header above (didn't show in the coding).